# Word meaning "has ability using physical objects"

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word to describe ability using physical objects. For example, someone who is particularly adept at using a computer, or nunchuks, or any physical object, could be said to have a lot of -----.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably referring to **manual ability or skills**

**[Manual skills](http://www.answers.com/topic/manual-skill)**

Ability to use one’s hands efficiently in the performance of a specific task or operation. An individual with a high degree of manual skill is said **to have a great deal of dexterity**. For example, a juggler has a great deal of manual skill.

Comment: Nice answer, manual ability is exactly what I mean. I always thought dexterity was just another word for agility, but googling the definition I see that it does say "especially with the hands".

Answer (score 1):

They have **dexterity**, or if they're good at fixing things you could say they are **handy**.

Answer (score 0):

A person who has a natural understanding or ability to manipulate physical objects is said to have a **mechanical** skill